# In Java HashMap, how to enforce a generic type to be a subclass

Tags: java, generics

I'm a class that keeps track of stuffs and their owners

```
public class Record<S,O> { //S - generic stuff,  O - generic owner
   HashSet<S> allStuffs;
   HashMap<S, O> whoOwnsWhat;
   // 
}
```

How can I enforce that S must be subclass of certain class/interface.

Thank you.

EDIT:
I modified Record to be "`class Record<Stuff,O>"` where Stuff is an abstract class, and got a warning "the type parameter Stuff is hiding the type Stuff".

`public class <S extends Stuff> Records<S,O>` also get a complier complaint.

Comment: You're edit is now asking a different question. You might want to ask that separately. Also, I think seeing more code would help in debugging the new error.

Comment: I think it is because you are trying to define allStuffs at class level and method level. Look at my answer.

Comment: public class <S extends Stuff, O> Records {...}. "public class <S extends Stuff> Records<S,O>{...}" - will not compile for suer. Show whole code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are extends and super keywords to define bounds for Java generics.

```
 public class Record<S extends fooClassName,O>  {
HashSet allStuffs(fooClassName arg); // do not "override" S by putting S HashSet<S> allStuffs; 
HashMap whoOwnsWhat (fooClassName arg1, O arg2);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public <S extends CharSequence> S foo(S s){
    return null;
}
```

States that class `S` must extend (be a subclass of) `CharSequence`.

Answer (score 0):

i am sure that wecan set a parent class or interface as the key or value of either set or map.
by doing that all the subclasses and implemented class of interface will be available to be inserted into either set or map.

```
HashMap<SuperClass, Interface>
```