# Ideas to enforce strict (better) type safety with a Java Interface as the parameter

Tags: java, generics, interface, type-safety

***Update*** based on inputs below.  Now and again I feel efforts for type-safe use of Java interfaces less than straightforward.

Here's a simple example of what we'd like to do: a design, following.  When it comes to implementation after several attempts to get type safety, I'm (*again*) discovering that we need to *think in Java* to encourage  Java to support our needs.  I'm made improvements on the original example.  I'm leaving the question open because there's probably a better way to go about things.

*Intention*:

1. Think of some different classes we want to put in a hash.
2. We want to manages these as a collection of ***ServiceProvider*** interface instances.
3. The idea is to make an OO design like this:

Service type:

```
public interface DisplaySettings    extends     ServiceInterface { ... }
```

Provider type:

```
public interface ServiceProvider    extends     ServiceInterface { ... }
```

Implementation:

```
    public class DisplayConfig extends Config  
                               implements DisplaySettings, ServiceProvider 
    { ... }
```

4. The challenge comes when we want to 'register' an implementation.  This is a method prototype for the ***desired*** method:

   ```
   public boolean registerService( final ServiceProvider newProvider )
   { ... }
   ```

   - The service implemented by newProvider is given by: newProvider.getServiceInterface()
5. And we'd like to call this kind of methods as follows:

   ```
   ServicesMgr.registerServiceProvider( this );
   ```
6. Thanks to suggestions below, the schema to ask for the a registered provider is to specify the interface as so:

   ```
   DisplaySettings videoSettings = ServicesMgr.getProvider( DisplaySettings.class );
   ```

Of course, you can't do that *!*  The only alternative that compiles is to use the "***.class***" to register and look-up the provider instance object.  Along with requisite changes to the tidy definitions above ...

```
    DisplaySettings videoSettings = ServicesMgr.getProvider( DisplaySettings.class );
```

Which looks a lot more type-safe.

The get provider call as suggested by @immibis ...

```
  public <InterfaceType extends ServiceInterface> ServiceProvider getProvider( Class<InterfaceType> interfaceClass )
  { ... }
```

Sadly that solution won't allow the HashMap to '*find*' the provider when it comes time to look it up.  It looks like the hash map will use the "Class" which doesn't identify the implementation class.  I have tried a few variations like:

```
  public Class<ServiceInterface>  getServiceType(){ ... }
```

And using the InterfaceType from above.  My understanding of what's happening is that this is challenging because there's only single inheritance.  `Class` is not: `Class`, where:

```
  <InterfaceType extends ServiceInterface>
```

At the moment I'm left with using: `public Class getServiceType(){...}`, as the consistent key.  Of course since we are devolved to just "Class" as a type it kind of voids type safety.  There's some protection by wrapping the `getServiceType` in a method.

Continuing to working on extracting type-protection from relevant looking examples:

- [Type-safe Hetrogenous Container Pattern](http://idlebrains.org/tutorials/java-tutorials/effective-java-typesafe-heterogeneous-container-pattern/)
- [Enforcing parameter types on dependent interfaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639579/enforcing-parameter-types-on-dependent-interfaces)
- [In Java HashMap, how to enforce a generic type to be a subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594236/in-java-hashmap-how-to-enforce-a-generic-type-to-be-a-subclass)

Neither look like what we are looking for (*yet*). Is this or something close possible?  I'm looking for ideas on how-to-do it?  Many thanks for your time.

Comment: I think I agree with "gauche" at least.  One way this is commonly done is with some sort of ID string: `ServicesMgr.get( "service:DisplaySetting" )` with the idea that the string itself is a "well known" ID.  [Similar to JDBC.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/overview/index.html)

Comment: Why do you want to pass `this` twice to `registerServiceProvider`?

Comment: @immibis ... yes, I agree.  I wanted to be explicit for the question.

Comment: @markspace ... Thanks, yes I was going to do that at first.  I just thought it would be good if we could find a method to wrap thing in a _type-safe_ way.  Strings don't have type, _per se_.  I doubt this is something that will 'work as intended' in Java.

Comment: @immibis ... actually, there's no way that I know to get the 'type-of' the interface passed as first parameter.  Ideally, the interface is the hash-key on the opaque type.

Comment: @will Have you tried passing the Class object?

Comment: @immibis ... Yes I'm using 'class' as described in the question -- However that's no more type-safe in the method signature than using a String or Object -- both ostensibly type-less.

Comment: You should have a good look at `java.util.ServiceLoader`. It's already done.

Comment: I believe what's really needed for this are **Mixins**.  @EJP ... The ServiceLoader loads homogenous providers.

Answer (score 2):

```
DisplaySettings videoSettings = ServicesMgr.getProvider( DisplaySettings.class );
```

is valid code, and type-safe, if `getProvider` is defined like this:

```
public <InterfaceType extends ServiceInterface> InterfaceType getProvider(Class<InterfaceType> interfaceClass) {
    ...
}
```

That should be easy enough to implement.

Your `registerServiceProvider` method also looks conceptually complex, but I don't see any questions you are asking about it.

Comment: @will Your edit was rejected because it should have been a comment. Also, the reason for your error is that this method conflicts with your other `getProvider` method. You can't have a `getProvider(Class<InterfaceType>)` and `getProvider(Class)` method in the same class.

Comment: Thanks I hadn't understood the syntax error on having two methods that look like different signatures: Class<InterfaceType> and Class.

Comment: The intention for the edit though, was to clarify that the getProvider method must return a provider type, not an InterfaceType since it is looking-up a hash (all said and done).  I at least have this compiling now, many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is a [Generic Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/boundedTypeParams.html)

In your case, you can do it like this:

```
public interface ServicesMgr {

    public <E> E getProvider(Class<E> clazz);
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
DisplaySettings displaySettings = mgr.getProvider(DisplaySettings.class);
```

This will enforce type checking, which is what you want.
The object returned by getProvider will need to be an instance of the Class that you pass to it.

Comment: Yes, they may be potential in a Manager-interface.  One point for readers though, is that this is essentially a hash operation.  When the input is 'E', we want a *ServiceProvider*  (that _implements_ E) back, not E.  I appreciate the ambiguity inherent due to the same class implementing two different though related interfaces: an  interface-duality.

Comment: Java does not offer multiple inheritance, so "No". that is not possible.

Comment: Your comment set me to thinking; I can pass _this_ to the register call this way -- I specified a **getServiceInterface()** method in the _ ServiceProvider interface_. We implemented that in the providers.  The register can use that to get the hash key!  You ask good questions, keep it up.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing sounds like the [type-safe heterogenous container](http://idlebrains.org/tutorials/java-tutorials/effective-java-typesafe-heterogeneous-container-pattern/) pattern, but I'm not sure if you can do it with interfaces.

Comment: The preferred goal is definitely a type safe container.  But the question is really, "how to achieve this FOR interfaces?"  Or, rather, is is possible - As you say, it may not be.  I've exhausted this weeks brain *lol* :-)

Comment: What happens when you attempt to use this pattern with interfaces?  (Some compiler errror, I assume.)  Would it be possible to use abstract classes where you are currently using interfaces?